# How to show legend for only one plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, legend

I am actually plotting 2 datasets in one plot, the first data set is just 1 file and the second dataset has 15 files.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
filelist=[]
for i in range (1,16):
    filelist.append("/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/Code/A_B_%s.txt" %i)
data1= pd.read_table('/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/Code/A_B_0.txt', dtype=float, header=None, sep='\s+').values
for fname in Filelist:
    data= pd.read_table(fname, dtype=float, header=None, sep='\s+').values
    t=np.arange(1,100,1)
    x=data[:,1]
    y=data1[:,1]
    plt.xlabel('Time Interval (Hours)')
    plt.ylabel('Energy')
    plt.plot(t,x,'HandleVisibility','off',linewidth=0.40) #thought it would stop the legend option for this plot
    plt.plot(t,y,'maroon', linewidth=1.2,label='Reference')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

But as the other file list contain 15 files, when I am only trying to show the legend for the Single Data File (data1), in the Legend Box, its appearing 15 times. Any way to turn off the legend option for the list of files (15) so that in the legend box of the single data file it appears just once?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick fix

```
....
label_name = None
if fname == filelist[0]: label_name = 'Reference'
plt.plot(t,y,'maroon', linewidth=1.2,label=label_name)
....
```

the legend  items are tied to the labeling, if you put a `None` in the label it should blank it.

In context of your code

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
filelist=[]
for i in range (1,16):
    filelist.append("/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/Code/A_B_%s.txt" %i)
data1= pd.read_table('/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/Code/A_B_0.txt', dtype=float, header=None, sep='\s+').values
for fname in filelist:
    data= pd.read_table(fname, dtype=float, header=None, sep='\s+').values
    t=np.arange(1,100,1)
    x=data[:,1]
    y=data1[:,1]
    plt.xlabel('Time Interval (Hours)')
    plt.ylabel('Energy')
    plt.plot(t,x,'HandleVisibility','off',linewidth=0.40) #thought it would stop the legend option for this plot

    label_name = None
    if fname == filelist[0]: label_name = 'Reference'
    plt.plot(t,y,'maroon', linewidth=1.2,label=label_name)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Will you please suggest how to adapt your approach to when there are 3 plots in the code, 1 plot is of the file list (15 files), the other 2 plots will have different labels. I tried but failed.